# python date str parse

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some string dates
ı try to calculate how much day have from today to string day
example string dates

```
examples=["June 30 - July 16","Thursday, July 15","July 9 - 19"]
```

I write for one type

```
import datetime
arriveTimes="June 30 - July 16"
dates=arriveTimes.split(" - ")
monthToNumber = {
'January' : 1,         
'February' : 2,         
'March' : 3,           
'April' : 4,              
'May' : 5, 
'June' : 6,
'July' : 7, 
'August' : 8, 
'September' : 9, 
'October' : 10, 
'November' : 11, 
'December' : 12}
firstMounth=""
arriveTimesOnDayList=[]
for date in dates:
    
    month,day=date.split(" ")
    
    
    month=str([v for k, v in monthToNumber.items() if month.lower() in k.lower()][0])
    today = datetime.datetime.now()
    year=str(today.year)
    dateTimeObj = datetime.datetime.strptime(year+"-"+month+"-"+day, '%Y-%m-%d')
    arriveTimeDatetimeObj = dateTimeObj - today
    arriveTimesOnDayList.append(str(arriveTimeDatetimeObj.days))
print(arriveTimesOnDayList)
arriveTimesOnDayStr=arriveTimesOnDayList[0]+"-"+arriveTimesOnDayList[1]
print(arriveTimesOnDayStr)
```

but I want it support all type

Comment: What is "all type"? As in all possible date format?

Comment: for example  it can be 

"Wednesday ,Thursday"

when today is Monday

Comment: example day interest today
if not letter than one week it is expressed as a days
if not letter than one month and letter than one week

Comment: Your first example seems to be more a _range_ of dates, the second one is a date, the third one maybe a range again. So how do you count the days from today when you have a range?

Comment: I am not use counter i use datetime object i try to turn from example dates to datetime object I subtract two date time objects from each other and find how many days it is

Comment: It's still unclear what you want, your code should calculate the time difference between today and another date. However, some of your example consist of two dates, assumed today is `June 27`, what is the expected result when example is `June 30 - July 16`? 2 or 18 or some time between? Perhaps you should add more examples to show what **all type** you want, and expected results for all of your examples to make it clear. By the way, I think your current code doesn't work.

Comment: @adamkwm I edited it is working for one type

Comment: I get "arrive times" from some websites. ı want to learn how many days have from today until arrival times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`datetime` doesn't have the functionality to parse arbitrary date string, you may need to find some libraries doing that.

`datetime.strptime()` needs fixed format so you need to keep all date strings in same format, or you may need to have a list of all formats you want, then try them one by one.

```
from datetime import datetime
def get_date(date):
    # %B for month full name, %A for weekday full name
    formats = ["%B %d", "%A, %B %d", "%d"]
    today = datetime.now()
    for f in formats:
        try:
            dt = datetime.strptime(f"{today.year} {date}", f"%Y {f}")
            # if the date is before today, treated as date in next month
            if dt < today:
                dt = dt.replace(month=today.month+1)
            return dt
        except ValueError:
            continue
    else:
        print("Date format not supported.")

def day_from_today(dates):
    for date in dates:
        dt = get_date(date)
        if dt:
            dft = (dt - datetime.now()).days
            print(f"{dft} {'days' if dft > 1 else 'day'} to {dt.date()}")

example = ["June 30", "July 16", "Thursday, July 15", "June 28", "19", "7 19"]
day_from_today(example)
```

Result:

```
2 days to 2021-06-30
18 days to 2021-07-16
17 days to 2021-07-15
0 day to 2021-06-28
21 days to 2021-07-19
Date format not supported.
```